# Azure Sql database export to Azure blob storage failed

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, azure-sql-server

I tried to export an azure Sql database to an azure blob storage via the Azuer portal and got an error:

```
Error encountered during the service operation. ; 
Exception Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac.Services.ServiceException:Unexpected exception encountered while retrieving metadata for blob https://<blobstoragename>.blob.core.windows.net/databases/<databaseName>_12.10.2020-11:13:24.bacpac;.; Inner exception Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException:The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.;
Inner exception System.Net.WebException:The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
```

In the blob storage account's firewall settings all networks access is denied. It's only possible to connect for selected networks and I activated the option "Allow trusted Microsoft services to access this storage account". The Sql Server and the storage have an private endpoint connection to the same network.

I setup an vm in the same network which was able to access the blob storage.

Is it possible to export a sql database to the azure storage when the public network access is denied? If yes, which setting am I missing?

Comment: COuld you please tell me how you do that?

Comment: Select in the Azure Portal any SQL database and in the menu at the top you'll see an export button

Comment: Hi @MartinAy, is the answer helpful for you?

Comment: Hi sorry for the late response. Yes it was helpful. Thank you, I missed the fact that it is not supported. We are using the azure cli https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql/db?view=azure-cli-latest#az_sql_db_export in an environment where I don't have an static public ip. Our workaround is to export the sql database to an public blob storage and copy it to a private one afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my research, when exporting a SQL database to the azure storage, the Azure Storage account behind a firewall is currently not supported. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-export). Besides, you can vote up the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/41442409-sql-export-to-support-storage-account-with-firewal) to make Microsoft improve the features.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Is it possible to export a sql database to the azure storage when the public network access is denied?**

Yes, it's impossible. But it will limit the access according the IP address.

If we only set the Storage firewall settings: `Allow access from Selected network` and `Allow trusted Microsoft services to access this storage account`, we will get the 403 error when access the storage from Azure SQL database.
[image]

The thing you missed is that when we set `Allow access from Selected network`, the Storage firewall will be more like Azure SQL database firewall settings! We can see there is an client IP in `Firewall` setting. We must add the client IP to the firewall then Azure SQL database could access it.

[image]